# Purple Screen and No Activity

Tags: dual-boot, compaq

I am installing 20.04 from Flash Drive on old Compaq SR1650NX with an updated Athlon 2-core processor installed in the 939 AM2 socket and a functional Win7 OS. After passing disk check, I get a purple screen and no activity thereafter. What must I do to install the dual-boot Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: I have resolved the issue by installing Xubuntu instead. It seems this old Compaq only has 3 GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You get the purple screen on ubuntu? if yes try to load a safe graphic versione, if there is, from grub and see if it works; if it does this is probably a gpu drivers problem